# How to extract a multiple column table from an image into a dataframe using OCR and pytesseract?

Tags: opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract a multiple column table from an image (PNG file) using pytesseract, and convert the data into a dataframe. I am using pytesseract to perform the OCR.

I first used OpenCV to determine where in the image the table was located. Then I used pytesseract to read the data in the table. Next, I used agglomerative clustering to  separate data into the multiple columns as shown in the table in the image. Lastly, I tried recreating each column and constructing a dataframe. However, my results are separating the text into too many columns. How can I change my parameters to improve my results? Or should I try another approach?

[image_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x32fF.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import imutils
from pytesseract import Output
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from tabulate import tabulate

args = {
    "image": image_file,
    "output": "results.csv",
    "min_conf": 0,
    "dist_thresh": 25.0,
    "min_size": 2, #2
}


image = cv2.imread(image_file) #PNG image file
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# initialize a rectangular kernel that is ~5x wider than it is tall,
# then smooth the image using a 3x3 Gaussian blur and then apply a
# blackhat morpholigical operator to find dark regions on a light background
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (500, 100))
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)

# compute the Scharr gradient of the blackhat image and scale the result into the range [0, 255]
grad = cv2.Sobel(blackhat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
grad = np.absolute(grad)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(grad), np.max(grad))
grad = (grad - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)
grad = (grad * 255).astype("uint8")

# apply a closing operation using the rectangular kernel to close gaps in between characters, 
#apply Otsu's thresholding method, and finally a dilation operation to enlarge foreground regions
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(grad, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(grad, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)


# find contours in the thresholded image and grab the largest one,
# which we will assume is the stats table
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
tableCnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
# compute the bounding box coordinates of the stats table and extract
# the table from the input image
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(tableCnt)
table = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]


# Set the PSM mode to detect sparse text, and then localize text in the table
options = "--psm 6" 
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(
    cv2.cvtColor(table, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB),
    config=options,
    output_type=Output.DICT)

# Initialize a list to store the (x, y)-coordinates of the detected text along with the OCR'd text itself
coords = []
ocrText = []

# loop over each of the individual text localizations
for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
    # extract the bounding box coordinates of the text region from
    # the current result
    x = results["left"][i]
    y = results["top"][i]
    w = results["width"][i]
    h = results["height"][i]

    # extract the OCR text itself along with the confidence of the
    # text localization
    text = results["text"][i]
    conf = int(float(results["conf"][i]))

    # filter out weak confidence text localizations
    if conf > args["min_conf"]:
        # update our text bounding box coordinates and OCR'd text,
        # respectively
        coords.append((x, y, w, h))
        ocrText.append(text)

# Extract all x-coordinates from the text bounding boxes, setting the y-coordinate value to zero
xCoords = [(c[0], 0) for c in coords]

# Apply hierarchical agglomerative clustering to the coordinates
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(
    n_clusters=None,
    affinity="manhattan",
    linkage="complete",
    distance_threshold=args["dist_thresh"])
clustering.fit(xCoords)

# Initialize our list of sorted clusters
sortedClusters = []

# loop over all clusters
for l in np.unique(clustering.labels_):
    # extract the indexes for the coordinates belonging to the
    # current cluster
    idxs = np.where(clustering.labels_ == l)[0]

    # verify that the cluster is sufficiently large
    if len(idxs) > args["min_size"]:
        # compute the average x-coordinate value of the cluster and
        # update our clusters list with the current label and the
        # average x-coordinate
        avg = np.average([coords[i][0] for i in idxs])
        sortedClusters.append((l, avg))

# sort the clusters by their average x-coordinate and initialize our
# data frame
sortedClusters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over the clusters again, this time in sorted order
for (l, _) in sortedClusters:
    # extract the indexes for the coordinates belonging to the
    # current cluster
    idxs = np.where(clustering.labels_ == l)[0]

    # extract the y-coordinates from the elements in the current
    # cluster, then sort them from top-to-bottom
    yCoords = [coords[i][1] for i in idxs]
    sortedIdxs = idxs[np.argsort(yCoords)]

    # generate a random color for the cluster
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3,), dtype="int")
    color = [int(c) for c in color]

    # loop over the sorted indexes
    for i in sortedIdxs:
        # extract the text bounding box coordinates and draw the
        # bounding box surrounding the current element
        (x, y, w, h) = coords[i]
        cv2.rectangle(table, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)

    # extract the OCR'd text for the current column, then construct
    # a data frame for the data where the first entry in our column
    # serves as the header
    cols = [ocrText[i].strip() for i in sortedIdxs]
    currentDF = pd.DataFrame({cols[0]: cols[1:]})

    # concatenate *original* data frame with the *current* data
    # frame (we do this to handle columns that may have a varying
    # number of rows)
    df = pd.concat([df, currentDF], axis=1)

# replace NaN values with an empty string and then show a nicely
# formatted version of our multi-column OCR'd text
df.fillna("", inplace=True)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))
```

[Result of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPfFK.png)

Comment: You can try and take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/table-transformer if you are open to using a model for your task